# "CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ReportDocuments' does not contain a definition for 'Load'" error while loading ReportDocuments

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
ReportDocuments Rdoc = new ReportDocuments();
string Apppath = Application.StartupPath;
string Reppath = @"reports\Report.rpt";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Apppath, Reppath);
Rdoc.Load(fullPath);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Rdoc;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

This code gives this error

> Error1'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ReportDocuments' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ReportDocuments' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\ACS\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\CrystalReportDemo\CrystalReportDemo\Form1.cs

at this line

```
Rdoc.Load(fullPath);
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: ReportDocuments is not a valid Crystal Report class; use new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ReportDocuments to ReportDocument.

Comment: Thank You Sir Its Working Now